# I have a dummy rpm. rpm -qpR lin.rpm

Tags: linux

I have a dummy `rpm` named `lin.rpm`. I wanted to know what are its dependency (to install) So i used below command to find dependency:-

```
rpm -qpR lin.rpm
```

I got below output:-

```
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
```

I am new to linux 
What does this mean Can any one help me out?
What does  `<=` symobl in linux means?

Answer (score 0):

You can read it [here in the rpm documentation for spec files](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/dependencies.html). A spec file is needed for rpbbuild to build a rpm file.
The version information is written as:

> `[epoch:]version[-release]`

Your output:

```
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
```

means that you need a version of `rpmlib(CompressedFileNames)` which is smaller or equal (`<=`) like `version 3.0.4 release 1` and `rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix)` which is smaller or equal (`<=`) like `version 4.0 release 1`.

Also the use of other conditionals is possible:

> Instead of `>=`, you may also use `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `=`.

They are: `greater or equal`,  `smaller`, `greater`, `smaller or equal` and `equal`.

Comment: Hi @Dhiru if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you need more details please feel free to ask.